# How should I fade out with CSS in the jQuery function

Tags: jquery, css

I have this jQuery function

```
 $(document).on('click', "a.delete-just-uploaded-selector", function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url + "/path/",
        data: info,
        success: function(){

        }
    });
       $(this).parents(".deleteimage").animate("fast")
        .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");          
        return false;
    });
```

See my fade out animation in the last part. I have read that it is better (faster and better for phones) using CSS transitions when it is simple animations insted of jQuery. But how do I do it? Using `.css()` in jQuery? I have an external stylesheet. I know how to do CSS transitions in pure css but not the best way to combine it with jQuery.

Comment: If you know the transition property have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with CSS it would be like

```
@keyframes fade {
    from { opacity: 1;}
    to {  opacity: 0; }
}

div.fade {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

And when you want to hide an element you should only add class `.fade`

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('.my-div').addClass('fade');
});
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shurshilin/cqbj02ob/1/

Comment: I think transition-duration instead of animation-duration will give him a nice fade :)

Comment: for me seems that fade'll look in the same way, but css code'll shorter and cleaner.

Comment: I think more correct to use animation-duration property with animation and transition-duration with transition. It lloks strange if we use animation keyframes and transition-duration for the same thing.

Comment: Don worry man .. I just let you know what happened  in chrome .. just for knowing .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `fadeOut()`.

```
$( "p" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
});
```

Also you have different options available for css properties.

Eg :

> `specialEasing` An object containing one or more of the CSS properties
>   defined by the properties argument and their corresponding easing
>   functions

More info [jquery fade out](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
.deleteimage{
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
</style>

<div class="deleteimage">Fade</div>

<script>
//...
$( ".deleteimage" ).animate({
    opacity: 0
}, "slow");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessary have to use `animation` and define it like that. You can just use `transition`:

```js
$('.someLink').on('click', function() {
  $('.myDiv').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.myDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  line-height: 1em;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease, line-height 500ms ease, padding 500ms ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease, line-height 500ms ease, padding 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 300ms ease, line-height 500ms ease, padding 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease, line-height 500ms ease, padding 500ms ease;
}

.myDiv.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  line-height: 0em;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv">Boo</div>
<a href="#" class="someLink">Click here</a>
```